# Visual Studio C++ remote debugging - running CMD as admin on remote machine

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, remote-debugging

I'm using *Visual Studio 2017* to debug C++ code on a VM running *Windows* via [VS Remote Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-cpp?view=vs-2017). As part of my code, I'm executing commands via `std::system`, which must run *as administrator* to be successful.

When running VS *as administrator*, and debugging the code **locally** -- all works fine.

But, when debugging **remotely** on a VM, the commands aren't executed *as administrator*. I know that for a fact, because some of the commands require that, and the output explicitly states that it's not the case. Is there a way to make it work?

I don't mind using a different API, `std::system` is just seems as the "default" for command execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Barrnet's answer, I've looked into `ShellExecuteEx` and its *"runas" verb*.

Here's a full solution, for running a cmd as admin and retrieving the cmd output as a string: (UAC has to be set to minimum, in order to avoid a pop-up)

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

inline void Validate (const bool expression) 
{
    if (!expression) 
        throw std::exception(); 
}

class TemporaryFile
{
public:
    TemporaryFile()
    {
        std::vector<char> tmpPath(MAX_PATH + 1, 0);
        Validate(0 != GetTempPathA(MAX_PATH, tmpPath.data()));
        std::vector<char> tmpFilename(MAX_PATH + 1, 0);
        Validate(0 != GetTempFileNameA(tmpPath.data(), "tmp", 0, tmpFilename.data()));
        _fullPath = std::string(tmpFilename.data());
    }

    ~TemporaryFile()
    {
        DeleteFileA(_fullPath.c_str());
    }

    std::string GetPath()
    {
        return _fullPath;
    }
    
private:
    std::string _fullPath{};
};

std::string ReadFileContents(const std::string& filename)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(filename);
    return std::string((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
}

std::string RunCmdAsAdmin(const std::string& cmd)
{
    // file to hold cmd output
    TemporaryFile output;

    // the cmd will be passed to cmd.exe via '/c' flag, output will be written to tempfile
    const std::string modifiedCmd = "/c " + cmd + " > \"" + output.GetPath() + "\"";

    // create and launch cmd (async operation -- a seperate process is launched)
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO shellExecInfo{};
    shellExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
    shellExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT | SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI | SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    shellExecInfo.lpVerb = "runas";
    shellExecInfo.lpFile = "cmd.exe";
    shellExecInfo.lpParameters = modifiedCmd.c_str();
    shellExecInfo.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
    Validate(TRUE == ShellExecuteEx(&shellExecInfo));

    // wait for cmd to finish running and retrieve output
    static const DWORD MAX_WAIT_MS{ 5000 };
    Validate(WAIT_OBJECT_0 == WaitForSingleObject(shellExecInfo.hProcess, MAX_WAIT_MS));
    CloseHandle(shellExecInfo.hProcess);
    return ReadFileContents(output.GetPath());
}

int main()
{
    const auto& cmdOutput = RunCmdAsAdmin("ipconfig"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you could set `Properties->Linker->Manifest File->UAC Execution Level` to `requireAdministrator`.

If you want to use Windows API, I find that [ShellExcuteEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/launch)  could meet your needs. Its structure is [SHELLEXECUTEINFOA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-shellexecuteinfoa). You could refer to the example:

```
var ExeInfo = SHELLEXECUTEINFO();
ExeInfo.lpVerb = “runas”;
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a great direction.